# How to detect SO_REUSEPORT availibility at run time?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, linux-kernel

For instance linux *kernel-2.6.32-279* does not define SO_REUSEPORT in /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h but *kernel-2.6.32-431* define it.

Then if I build some code like :

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int createsock()
{
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
#ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT,(const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0) 
    {
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    return sock;
}
```

The executable built with kernel-2.6.32-431, it works correctly with kernel-2.6.32-431, but doesnot work with kernel-2.6.32-279. 
If it is built with kernel-2.6.32-279, it works on both.

This code detect the option availability at build time, and it could be different at run time.

What could be a way to detect at runtime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the [`setsockopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsockopt.html) call fails, you check [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) to see what went wrong. If it's `EINVAL` or `ENOPROTOOPT` the socket option is invalid, and you continue with other things.

If you're afraid something might happen, call [`getsockopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getsockopt.html) first, checking `errno` the same way if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

What about `getsockopt`? [Manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/setsockopt/)

With getsockopt you can check the return code for `[ENOPROTOOPT] The option is unknown at the level indicated`. without touching the option.

From the manpage:

```
The following options are recognized at the socket level.  Except as
noted, **each may be examined with getsockopt()** and set with setsockopt().

       (...)
       SO_REUSEPORT    enables duplicate address and port bindings
       (...)
```

Comment: That was only a listing of all the socket options, the OP already knows what SO_REUSEPORT is. The info in the comment you had is what the OP needs

Comment: @nos i thought he misset the line about **each may be examined with getsockopt()** and that it existed in the options.